# how to extract the subset from a special character string using perl

Tags: perl

I need to get the subset of a string starting from a specific start word and end before the specified word. Store in the string variable.

Example: `pre-wrap">test-for??maths/camp`

I need to fetch the subset.

Expected output:  `test-for??maths`

After: `pre-wrap">` or may be starting with: `test`

and before: `/camp`

I have no clue how to achieve this in Perl.

Here is the code I tried. The output is not coming as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = 'pre-wrap">test-for??maths/camp';
my $quoted_substring = quotemeta($string);
my ($quoted_substring1) = split('/camp*', $quoted_substring);
my (undef, $substring2) = split('>\s*', $quoted_substring1);

print $string, "\n";
print $substring2, "\n";
```

Output:

```
$ perl test.pl
pre-wrap">test-for??maths/camp
test\-for\?\?maths\         # but why this \ is coming
```

Comment: A good starting point would be to learn Perl. And then, have a look at [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). If I misunderstood and you already tried to solve your problem but didn't manage to, then show us your code and explain what's not working.

Comment: here is what i tried:#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = 'pre-wrap">test-for??maths/camp';
my $quoted_substring = quotemeta($string);
my ($quoted_substring1) = split('/camp*', $quoted_substring);

print $string, "\n";
print $quoted_substring1, "\n";

Comment: The `\` is coming because you call `quotemeta` on the string which you want to scan. This is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks it is working now

Comment: `or may be starting with: test` what does that mean?  show an example where that would make a difference from just `after: pre-wrap">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code extracts the part between `$before` and `$after` (which may contain regex metacharacters, they are treated as pure characters inside the `\Q...\E` expressions):

```
my $string = 'pre-wrap">test-for??maths/camp';

my $before = 'pre-wrap">';
my $after  = '/camp';

if ($string =~ /\Q$before\E(.*?)\Q$after\E/) {
  print $1;  # prints 'test-for??maths'
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. this is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`pre-wrap">test-for??maths/camp` is in 'd',

```
perl -ne '/((?<=pre-wrap">)|(?<=>)(?=test))\S+(?=\/camp)/  ; print $&' d
```